# Is there a record of Monero OTC trading before it was listed on an exchange?

Tags: history, trading-volume, otc-trading

Before Monero was added to its first exchange:

- What was the first recorded price (in Bitcoin) for a Monero trade?
- What was the highest and lowest OTC price for Monero??
- How much OTC trading volume was there at the time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, to answer your first question. Yes, there is a record of Monero OTC trading before it was listed on an exchange, which can be found [here](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=578192.0).

The OTC trading thread was started on April 22, 2014, whereas Monero launched on April 18, 2014. Therefore, undoubtly there have been some trades before aforementioned thread was launched. Most trades, however, likely happened in a private manner and thus are unrecorded. An exception is [this](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=577296) "auction", where smooth [traded](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=577296.msg6319040#msg6319040) 0.025 BTC for 1.2 XMR, which is a price of 0.0208 BTC/XMR. This trade was done on April 21, 2014 and therefore most likely the first recorded price (in Bitcoin) for a Monero trade.

> What was the highest and lowest OTC price for Monero??

Looking at the reported trades in the OTC [thread](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=578192.0), it seems that the highest price was recorded at 0.001750 and the lowest price recorded at 0.000200. This excludes smooth's trade, of which I am not entirely sure if that was the right price.

> How much OTC trading volume was there at the time?

From the reported trades in the opening post of the OTC thread we can see that a total of 86 trades occured over 24 days. The cumulative volume of these trades is approximately 134k Monero. This gives an average volume of approximately 5.6k Monero per day. In addition, the largest trade is a trade for 8000 Monero, whereas the smallest trade is a trade for 50 Monero.